# spacing within a grid element(issue)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
     [class^="box-"]{
            background-color: skyblue;
         display: grid;
         place-items: center;
        
        }
        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            display: grid;
            gap: 20px;
            height: 100vh;

            grid-template-areas: 
            " A A A A  A A B B  B B B B"
            " A A A A  A A B B  B B B B"
           
            
        }
        .box-1{
            grid-area: A;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;   }
        .box-2{
            grid-area: B;
        }
        .box-3{
            grid-area: C;
       box-4 {
           grid-area: D;
       }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
     
    </header>
    <section>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="box-1">
                <h1>Hello, I am Michael.<br> </h1>
                <p>a developer in the making</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-2"></div>
            <div class="box-3">c</div>
            <div class="box-4">d</div>
            

            
        </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
```

[image]

I am having an issue with spacing within my grid boxes. When I add an h1 element and a p element, I do not want a large amount of spacing between these two. I have tried to fix it by changing the padding and margins but it hasn't worked. I do not know if there is a certain way to target the spacing within gridboxes. If anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

```
<style>
    *{
        box-sizing:border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }
    body{
        background-image: url(images/);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 100vh;
        
        
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    header{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 30px 70px;
    }
    .nav-area {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .nav-area li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    .nav-area li a{
        color: black;
    }
    [class^="box-"]{
        background-color: skyblue;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
    
    }
    .container {
        display: grid;
        gap: 20px;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-areas: 
        " A A A A  A A B B  B B B B"
        " A A A A  A A B B  B B B B"
       
        
    }
    .box-1{
        grid-area: A;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .box-2{
        grid-area: B;
    }
    .box-3{
        grid-area: C;
     }

   .box-4 {
       grid-area: D;
   }
```

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I added a snippet of my issue. I really just want the paragraph right below the h1.

Answer (score 0):

Just align the items relative to the parent grid container by using `align-content` and use `text-align` to actually center its text. Change it to:

```
[class^="box-"]{
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```